# Nhibernate how to do inner join and match mode together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, nhibernate

I have been research it for a while now on the net, but non of them really make and sense for me .. maybe I am new to Hibernate.

however customer table suppose to join customerProduct table then join product table 
and I have a string product variable I would like to able match the product table Name value column 
..
in SQL SERVER the query i wanted to do

```
select c.Name, c.Address1, c.Address2, c.County, p.Name
from dbo.Customers as c inner join dbo.CustomerProducts as cp
    on c.CustomerID = cp.CustomerID inner join dbo.Products as p 
     on cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
where c.Address1 ='&somthing&' and c.Name='&somthing&' and c.Address1='&somthing&' and p.Name='&somthing&'
```

however this is what i have at the moment and i cant think of how to do a inner join in Nhibernate 
and put string product variable to search product table

```
public IPagedList<Customer> GetSearchPagedCustomer(string product, string practice, string address, string county, int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 100)
        {
            ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Customer>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(product))
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("Product.Name",product,MatchMode.Anywhere));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(practice))
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("Name", practice,MatchMode.Anywhere));

            //One value and search 3 column: address 1, address 2 and address 3
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
                criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("Address1", address, MatchMode.Anywhere) || Restrictions.Like("Address2", address, MatchMode.Anywhere) || Restrictions.Like("Address3", address, MatchMode.Anywhere));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(county))
            criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("County", county, MatchMode.Anywhere));

        return criteria.Future<Customer>().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToPagedList<Customer>(pageNumber, pageSize);
    }
```

Can anyone convert that SQL query code to Nhibernate code for me,, 
Thank very much for the you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your mapping would be `<bag>` with `<many-to-many>` and The Customer has a collection Products:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    ...
```

Then the way how to do a join would be like this:

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<Customer>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(product))
{
     // here we do LEFT JOIN on Products
     var productCriteria = criteria
          .CreateCriteria("Products", "Product", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

     // the subcriteria targeting the products table
     productCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("Name",product,MatchMode.Anywhere));
} 
...
```

And also, we can do paging and sorting on the server

```
criteria
    .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
    .SetFirstResult(0) // calculate from pageNumber
    .AddOrder(new Order("Name", true))
    .Future<Customer>()
    //.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    //.ToPagedList<Customer>(pageNumber, pageSize)
;
```